# StaleElementException within a foreach loop of IWebElements c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, foreach

So my issue is as follows, I am attempting to check all elements on the page and verify `element.GetAttribute("class") == expectedClass`. Here is the code

```
 var feedback = Driver.FindElements(AuctivaSalesPageModel.ViewFeedbackSelector);
            var attempts = 0;
            foreach (IWebElement element in feedback)
            {
                while (attempts < 3)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Assert.AreEqual("leaveFeed actionTaken", element.GetAttribute("class"));
                        attempts = 0;
                        break;

                    }
                    catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
                    {
                        Assert.AreEqual("leaveFeed actionTaken", element.GetAttribute("class"));
                        attempts = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (AssertionException)
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                        Driver.Navigate().Refresh();
                        AuctivaSalesPage.WaitForElementVisible(Driver, AuctivaSalesPageModel.TotalNumberOfSalesSelector);
                        AuctivaSalesPage.ScrollToTop();
                        AuctivaSalesPage.SelectNoFolder();
                        attempts++;
                    }

                }

            }
```

Now I have been reading up on the StaleElementException and I think that my catch and retry approach is useless as if the DOM has refreshed then the element within the list will always be stale. I believe what I need to do here is refind the element with a `Driver.FindElement()` but being that I am encountering this issue within a foreach loop of IWebElements I am not sure how to get the selector for the specific element that is failing to retry? 
Should I catch the exception rebuild the list and then retry the whole foreach loop? or is there a way to extract the selector specific to the `element` within the loop so I can do something along the lines of

`Assert.AreEqual("leaveFeed actionTaken", Driver.FindElement(By.someSelector(element.GetSelector)).GetAttribute("class"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps, but i had a similar problem and was able to get around it using the following logic, granted its not the best approach but it works:

```
var feedbackCount = Driver.FindElements(AuctivaSalesPageModel.ViewFeedbackSelector).Count();
var attempts = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < feedbackCount; i++)
{
    while (attempts < 3)
    {
        var element = Driver.FindElements(AuctivaSalesPageModel.ViewFeedbackSelector).ElementAt(i);
        //Continue you logic here
    }
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks so much `.ElementAt()` was exactly what I was looking for!